# Trouble animating an image, Seems Storyboard doesn't start

Tags: wpf

My Code is posted Below.  I am creating an image, and attempting to add animation to it.  I am sure it was working at one point, I made a small change, it failed I undid the change (literally undo) and now it continues to fail.  I am attempting to make an image change ever half second to another image, then change back after another half second.

```
<Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,90,0,0" Name="OldMan" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Source="/TestingWpF;component/Images/Old1.png" >
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="OldMan" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/TestingWpF;component/Images/Old1.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.0000000">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/TestingWpF;component/Images/Old2.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have your duration set.  You'll just get the first keyframe, but not the next.  Try adding something like `Duration="00:00:01.5"` to `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`

Comment: Duration was the problem thanks.  For the record I changed the animation to start at 0:0:0  and 0:0:0.5 and set duration to 0:0:01  this made a nice balanced flow  I will mark as answer as soon as it lets me